# laravel автозаполнение поля в бд без этого поля в форме

Tags: laravel

Как при регистрации заносить в столбик 'level' string значение 'user' в контроллере и не делать при этом инпута level в форме.

```
$validateFields = $request->validate([
            'Name' => 'required|string',
            'Surname' => 'string',
            'Patronymic' => 'string',
            'Login' => 'required|string|unique:users,Login',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',
        ]);

$user = User::create($validateFields);
```

так происходит регистрация

Comment: что вам мешает после валидации добавить его в массив?

Comment: спасибо за совет я нашёл подходящий мне способ при миграции добавить значение по умолчанию
$table->string('level')->default('user'); ваш совет тоже подходит но мне удобней так) ещё раз спасибо)

Comment: @bleckVirus Это единственный правильный способ с точки зрения SQL прописывать default значение, если это обычная строка/число/boolean. В ином случае это уже костыли.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar да спасибо уже понял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос наверное глупый был в итоге сделал при миграции значение по умолчани

```
$table->string('level')->default('user');
```

Answer (score 1):

Также автоматически вносить значение в определенное поле можно через модель. Например:

```
protected $attributes = [
    'level' => 'user'
];
```